# Setting new value in select2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using a bootstrap plugin 'select2'. Creating a custom value in select2 dropdown using the following code.

```
postPurchasePageSelect: function(){

$("#purchase_page_select").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select type',
    theme: "bootstrap",
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
  })
  .on('select2:open', () => {
    $(".select2-results:not(:has(a))").append(

      '<a href"" onclick="add_new_tag()" style="padding: 6px;height: 20px;display: inline-table;">Create new item</a>'

      );
  });

}


var add_new_tag = function(){

  var el = $(purchase_page_select);
  var newval = prompt("Enter new value: ");

      if(newval !== null) {
        el.append('<option>'+newval+'</option>')
          .val(newval);
      }
}
```

Everything is working fine but the line *.val(newval);* is replacing the previous all tags from the select2 field and setting a new value. I want to add a new tag with out removing the previous tags.

Comment: Well then remove `.val(newval)` …?

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: then it will not update the new value. I want to add the new tag in select2 field.